# Bash script to display Mac Airport MAC address

Tags: macos, bash, scripting, freebsd

I'm not good at scripting but found this site so hopefully some kind people out there can help me :)

I need a bash script to display the Airport Mac Address of machines, I think the command is..

```
ifconfig en1
```

..which brings up the correct result in Terminal but I dont know how to utilise this.

I'm using Casper Suite in an office environment and need to get a report that display the MAC address of the wireless (airport) ports.

To show you how Casper works here's a script that someone wrote to check if a machine has an Airport card or not

```
#!/bin/sh

checkHasAnAirportCard=`networksetup -listallhardwareports | grep "Hardware Port: Air" | cut -c 16-`

if [ -z "$checkHasAnAirportCard" ]; then
    echo "<result>No</result>"
else
    echo "<result>Yes</result>"
fi
```

Thanks for your help & suggestions

Comment: Do you actually want to do this for FreeBSD as tagged, or it it really Mac OS X ?

Comment: What's the output from `ifconfig en1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

networksetup -listallhardwareports | egrep -A 2 "(AirPort|Wi-Fi)" | grep Ethernet
```

Put this in a text file called e.g. `airport.sh`, make it executable (`chmod +x airport.sh`) and run it:

```
$ ./airport.sh 
Ethernet Address: 58:b0:35:65:7a:02
```

If you just want the MAC address on its own (without the "Ethernet Address: " prefix) then change the script to this:

```
#!/bin/sh

networksetup -listallhardwareports | egrep -A 2 "(AirPort|Wi-Fi)" | grep Ethernet | cut -f 3- -d ' '
```

This should then give e.g.:

```
$ ./airport.sh 
58:b0:35:65:7a:02
```

Comment: Lion calls its wireless interfaces "Wi-Fi" instead of "AirPort", so I'd recommend using `egrep -A 2 "Hardware Port: (AirPort|Wi-Fi)"` in the relevant spots.

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks - I'm still on Snow Leopard here so couldn't test this on Lion - I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you (the meat of the script is `ifconfig en1 | egrep -o "([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}"`):

```
#!/bin/sh

IFACE=en1 ##Put your interface here if it isn't en1

MACADDRESS=`ifconfig ${IFACE} | egrep -o "([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}"`

if [ -n "$MACADDRESS" ]; then
    # Found a mac address, print it out
    echo "$MACADDRESS"
else  
    # No mac found, do something else
fi
```

Outputs the mac address:

```
[ 16:15 Jonathan@MacBookPro ~ ]$ ./macMac.sh 
62:c5:4a:8c:c2:74
```

The `-n` tests if `$MACADDRESS` is empty or not.
`egrep -o` searches for that specific regex and only returns the match, not the entire line.

Comment: Works, but assumes that Airport will always be on `en1`.