# Shell/Unix - Getting MAC Address

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to know how we get our MAC address on an UNIX environment, I know already `ifconfig -...` but I'm getting others stuff too (I just want the MAC address, nothing more).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash script to display Mac Airport MAC address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973887/bash-script-to-display-mac-airport-mac-address)

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated on linux (see https://serverfault.com/questions/458628/should-i-quit-using-ifconfig)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible ?

As the root user (or user with appropriate permissions

```
Type "ifconfig -a"
```

From the displayed information, find eth0 (this is the default first Ethernet adapter),locate the number next to the HWaddr. This is your MAC address..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ifconfig|sed -n "1p"|tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f5
```